# esbuild outputting .css files to .js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, esbuild

I setup esbuild with a sinatra app and I'm trying to bundle my CSS using the esbuild.config.js below. The problem is the css file is being output as .js. What am I doing wrong here?

```js
import * as esbuild from 'esbuild';
import {sassPlugin} from 'esbuild-sass-plugin';
import * as path from 'path';

await esbuild.build({
  entryPoints: ["./assets/javascripts/application.js", 
                "./assets/stylesheets/application.css"],
  bundle: true,
  outdir: "./public",
  absWorkingDir: path.join(process.cwd()),
  watch: true,
  // custom plugins will be inserted is this array
  plugins: [sassPlugin({
    type: 'stylesheet'
  })],
}).catch(() => process.exit(1));
```

Here is the output:

public/stylesheets/application.js

```
(() => {
  // assets/stylesheets/application.css
  var application_default = `
p {
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
}`;
})();
```

Comment: Have you tried using a different "type"? `type: 'stylesheet'` is not documented. https://www.npmjs.com/package/esbuild-sass-plugin#user-content-options